# What can I do if there is no CC ported license in my country?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

**Background:**

Suppose I am developing an open source project. I am at the stage where I need to license my software. After doing research I find out that I live in a place where there is no ported CC license.

**My question:**

What do I do if the CC license I want to use has not yet been ported in my country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creative Commons recommends that you use their international licenses now. From their FAQ:

> We recommend that you use a version 4.0 international license. This is the most up-to-date version of our licenses, drafted after broad consultation with our global network of affiliates, and it has been written to be internationally valid. There are currently no ports of 4.0, and it is planned that few, if any, will be created.
>
> All of the ported licenses are at version 3.0 or earlier, which means licensors using those licenses do not have the benefit of the improvements made in the 4.0 license suite. But even before considering the improvements in 4.0, there are several reasons why the international licenses may be preferable for rights holders, even if the licenses have been ported to their jurisdiction. As an organization, CC itself licenses all of its own content under an international license because, among other reasons, the international licenses are essentially jurisdiction-neutral while remaining effective globally. The neutral nature of the international licenses appeals to many people and organizations, particularly for use in connection with global projects that transcend political borders. Finally, it is important to know that some of the ported licenses contain a choice of law provision, which may be undesirable for your needs.

With the Version 4.0 licenses, there will be no ported versions. Creative Commons itself licenses their own content under the international license, to remain jurisdiction-neutral. The neutral nature appeals to many people and organizations.

To answer your question: If there is no ported license, you can use the International licenses.